# Missing packages folder and smart.json file in Meteor.js 0.9

Tags: meteor, package

It may be a dumb question but I upgraded `meteor.js to meteor 0.9` and now, when I add packages, I do not see `/packages folder` or `smart.json` file in the root of my project. How can I reach to the source code of the downloaded packages. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of the downloaded packages is in a semi compiled state, nothing like what you would find on github.

To access these have a look at `~/.meteor/packages`. You would find them with the new notation e.g for `iron:router` you would see `iron/router` instead (depends on your OS if : is used instead)

Comment: I am using Mac. For example, in the previous version, I was using fullcalendar package and I was able to access its css file under/packages folder, and I could change it. Is it possible to do it in the new release of meteor?

Comment: You can access the css files there and edit them, but it would be very hard to add new files in. Basically its nearly the same thing, except there is no package.js & the files are concatenated

Comment: I just started meteor development that's why I am a newbie, can you please tell me how can I open the css file of the package, in .meteor/packages I only see the names of the packages.

Comment: I wouldn't advise this practice. It would be better to fork the repository on github for the package and clone it into your /packages folder. Then add it in using `meteor add` manually using the folder name you used in packages.

Comment: Akshat, this doesn't answer the question. OP isn't looking for a list of packages (that part is trivial), but the new location of the downloaded package source code, previously at `/packages`. You've claimed you can "access the files", but haven't specified exactly where.

Comment: @Zach ive specified quite precisely. They are in `~/.meteor/packages`. Fire up a terminal and have a look. You'll get a list of all the packages you've installed (on any app) in that directory. That is not the list of packages, it is the packages source code in precompiled form, as stated in the answer.

Comment: Just to be clear thats not `./.meteor/packages`, its `~/.meteor/packages`, the `~/` bit meaning your user's home directory.

Comment: Thanks – I was making the mistake suggested in your last comment.

Comment: I have the same problem. This packages doesn't have a github repo, so I can't use it unless I can review the source code. Is there anyway to do that?
https://atmospherejs.com/tkornblit/icheck