# Installing all packages from existing Meteor project into new project

Tags: git, meteor, nitrous

Here is my meteor repo:

https://github.com/the1mills/oresoftware_meteor

I cloned it into a new directory on Nitrous.io, but it's missing the smart packages in the packages directory, and as Meteor .gitignores those, and I have to re-install them.

I assume there is a way to install them intelligently using the info in the smart.lock file or smart.json file.

Do I have to install them individually by name and by my personal memory or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

There is a file called packages in the hidden .meteor folder. Packages lists all of the meteor packages you have installed through the command line. You can copy the file from one project to another, then start the new project up, you will be up to date.

Beware when doing this for different versions of meteor; like from pre 0.9.0 to now.

Tip: You can even modify this file while meteor is running, save it, and meteor will install/remove packages and restart your app. I never use the command line to manage packages.

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, if you want to load a package directly from a Git
>   repository (i.e. it’s neither available locally or hosted on
>   Atmosphere), you’ll also need to use Meteorite for now.

From [Updating to 0.9.0 What You Need to Know](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/updating-to-090/).

Also take a look into this [Akshat answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545934/missing-packages-folder-and-smart-json-file-in-meteor-js-0-9)r, (i think is relevant because this line)

> The source code of the downloaded packages is in a semi compiled
>   state, nothing like what you would find on github.